# MessageSecurityException for WCF customBinding UsernameOverTransport for WSSE

Tags: wcf, soap, ws-security, wsse

I need to implement a WCF service that conforms to the specs set forth by [Phase II CORE 270 Connectivity Rule](http://www.caqh.org/pdf/EDITED5010/270-v5010.pdf). 
I generated the service using `svcutil.exe` and the supplied [wsdl](http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.wsdl).

Given that we had chosen to handle security through username/password over SSL and the requirement for SOAP 1.2 addressing, I configured the service as a

customBinding:

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceBinding">
      <security 
        authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
        messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

The `WSDL` produced matches that of the `WSDL` provided by the spec. Using a supplied soap message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="true">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-21621663">
      <wsse:Username>bob</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-usernametoken-profile-1.0#PasswordText">bobPW</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd">
      <PayloadType> X12_270_Request_005010X279A1004010X092A1</PayloadType>
      <ProcessingMode>RealTime</ProcessingMode>
      <PayloadID>f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6</PayloadID>
      <TimeStamp>2007-08-30T10:20:34Z</TimeStamp>
      <SenderID>HospitalA</SenderID>
      <ReceiverID>PayerB</ReceiverID>
      <CORERuleVersion>2.2.0</CORERuleVersion>
      <Payload><![CDATA[ISA*00* *00* *ZZ*NEHEN780 *ZZ*NEHEN003 ...IEA*1*000000031]]></Payload>
    </ns1:COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and `SoapUI`, I am receiving a

> `System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException`, `System.ServiceModel`,
>   Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.

It would seem that the service does not understand the wsse namespace prefix as if I flip the namespace prefix to `o` the service does not have an issue with the request.

**EDIT**

I cannot seem to find the mismatch in the binding or an issue with their message indicating I am chasing up the wrong tree. Any other potential leads would be helpful. Is there a way to make a custom binding with `SOAP` 1.2 addressing inter-operable with the provided `SOAP` message?

Comment: Namespace prefixes don't matter at all to any competent XML processor. In fact, if the namespace prefix matters, then it is not an XML processor at all, but is only processing something which _resembles_ XML.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I had written a C# client to connect as well that indicated the service's misunderstanding of the namespace, but now I can see it was an ill-formatted soap header. Only other instance of this error message I saw related to WCF was the client needing to receive back a passed in timestamp.